# Discarding unknown changes in sample space

Tags: probability

I'm looking for some kind of reason/proof for a law in probability.

Imagine that we have a box with $5$ red and $5$ blue balls, indistinguishable.

It's easy to prove that if we take a ball out and not look at it, then the probability of the next ball being red is still $5/10$:

$P = 5/10 \cdot 5/9 + 5/10 \cdot 4/9 = 0.5$

this law is also right when we put $m \lt 10$ balls aside without looking.

actually we are changing the sample space but it's unknown so we ignore it. why?

Comment: Because you don’t look into any ball, so by putting some balls aside you don’t  have any new information than you had before, thus you are in the same settings, so probability is preserved regardless putting some balls aside since you don’t see them. Yes, you change the sample space, but information you have, is still the same.

Comment: Actually I think this depends on your definition of the sample space.  One can (be tedious and) argue that a sample point should represent the entire sequence of draws.  Then your event is "the last ball in the sequence is red" and you would argue from symmetry that it is 0.5.  (E.g., if you flip the color of every ball in the sequence you get an equi-probable sample point.)  My point is, if you use this (over-)detailed definition of sample space, then you cannot say you're "changing the same space" by performing the previous draws.